# Remove empty folders (Python)

Tags: python, directory

This is the folder tree:

```
FOLDER\\
       \\1\\file
       \\2\\file
       \\3\\
       \\4\\file
```

The script should scan (loop) for each folder in FOLDER and check if the sub-folders are empty or not. If they are, they must be deleted.

My code, until now, is this:

```
folders = ([x[0] for x in os.walk(os.path.expanduser('~\\Desktop\\FOLDER\\DIGITS\\'))])
folders2= (folders[1:])
```

This scan for folders and, using `folders2` begin from the firs folder in `DIGITS`.
In `DIGITS` there are numbered directories: 1,2,3,4,etc

Now what? Tried using `os.rmdir` but it gives me an error, something about string. In fact, `folders2` is a list, not a string, just saying...

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Not sure what kind of error you get, this works perfectly for me:

```
import os

root = 'FOLDER'
folders = list(os.walk(root))[1:]

for folder in folders:
    # folder example: ('FOLDER/3', [], ['file'])
    if not folder[2]:
        os.rmdir(folder[0])
```

Comment: I mean in a for loop. Maybe I was wrong...Anyway, the answer do the job perfectly.

Comment: yep, this solution will not work in a few cases like: 
1) recursion (if there are folders deeper than 1 level)
2) if folder has inner folders but has not files in it

Comment: Which is what I want for this specific case. Thanks.

Comment: Although this answers the question, has many issues! 1. What if root directory is empty? 2. What happens if a directory had all sub directories only? 3. You are converting the generator to a list just to skip the first element which you don't need to.

Answer (score 19):

A few things to expand on other answers:

If you use `os.walk(topdown=False)`, it goes in reverse order, so you encounter the child directories before the parents. Then if you track which directories you've deleted, you can delete parent directories recursively.

```py
import os


def delete_empty_folders(root):

    deleted = set()
    
    for current_dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(root, topdown=False):

        still_has_subdirs = False
        for subdir in subdirs:
            if os.path.join(current_dir, subdir) not in deleted:
                still_has_subdirs = True
                break
    
        if not any(files) and not still_has_subdirs:
            os.rmdir(current_dir)
            deleted.add(current_dir)

    return deleted
```

Comment: This is the best answer, it is the only answer that does not involve make a list of potentially millions of entries.

Answer (score 15):

You can remove all empty folders and subfolder with the following snippet.

```
import os


def remove_empty_folders(path_abs):
    walk = list(os.walk(path_abs))
    for path, _, _ in walk[::-1]:
        if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
            os.remove(path)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    remove_empty_folders("your-path")
```

Comment: `os.remove(path)` should be [`os.rmdir(path)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.rmdir)

Comment: It does not have to be absolute path. Relative paths also work.

Comment: The first two lines in the function can be replaced with a more idiomatic `for path, _, _ in os.walk(path_abs, topdown=False)`

Answer (score 6):

Delete folder only if it is empty:

```
import os
import shutil

if len(os.listdir(folder_path)) == 0: # Check if the folder is empty
    shutil.rmtree(folder_path) # If so, delete it
```

Comment: You will want to add `import shutil` to the imports in your answer

Comment: You can shoot yourself in a leg with that, since os.listdir does not always correctly return files on network shares (e.g. "hang" nfs being in a process of re-mounting will show 0 in the moment of unmount), shutil.rmtree might leave you without files in those cases...

Comment: Hey @Anubioz, I did not come across the case as you describe, but I learned something, thanks :)

Answer (score 3):

```
import os

directory = r'path-to-directory'

for entry in os.scandir(directory):
    if os.path.isdir(entry.path) and not os.listdir(entry.path) :
        os.rmdir(entry.path)
```

Here you can find a good introduction/explanation to [scandir](https://github.com/benhoyt/scandir/)

Comment: Would you mind editing your answer to help readers understand why this approach might be preferable over the accepted answer (or, really, any of the previous three answers)?

Comment: If you are going to use scandir, I think you don't get as much benefit if you use os.path.isdir() instead of entry.is_dir() - the whole point is that it is faster by not needing additional stat() calls, and os.path.isdir() is doing that stat() call, isn't it?

Comment: This only removes empty directories directly within the target directory but does not search the directory tree for empty directories to remove.

Answer (score 3):

Almost what Iván B. said but with a minor change that worked for me

```py
import os, shutil
path_abs=('YourPath')
walk = list(os.walk(path_abs))
for path, _, _ in walk[::-1]:
    if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
        os.rmdir(path)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
#LOOP THROUGH ALL SUBFOLDERS FIRST

import os
root = os.getcwd() #CHANGE THIS TO PATH IF REQUIRED
folders = sorted(list(os.walk(root))[1:],reverse=True)
for folder in folders:
    try:
        os.rmdir(folder[0])
    except OSError as error: 
        print("Directory '{}' can not be removed".format(folder[0]))
```

This should go through all the sub-folders first and remove if empty folders. Not deleting non empty folders that a parent folders.

I know it an old post but I am old myself !!!

Answer (score 1):

For empty folders deletion you can use this snippet.

```
import os


def drop_empty_folders(directory):
    """Verify that every empty folder removed in local storage."""

    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(directory, topdown=False):
        if not dirnames and not filenames:
            os.rmdir(dirpath)
```

Comment: This does not work for folder with empty child folder. Child folder gets deleted but parent - even though is evaluated after deleting child - still sees the child folder in dirnames. Although topdown=False is nice.

Answer (score 1):

This answer fixes issues in the current accepted answer. The major issue there is that the condition to remove a directory has to be `not filenames and not dirnames`.

```
import os

def remove_empty_directories(root):
    for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(root):
        if not filenames and not dirnames:
            os.rmdir(dirpath)
```

Comment: This seems to duplicate [an earlier answer from 2020](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61925409/874188) with a comment pointing out a bug in it.

Answer (score 1):

**If you are on UNIX system**, you can use the "find" command in a python script with subprocess.
You search for directories with : -type d
You select empty directories with : -empty
You delete these directories with : -delete
You launch the command with subprocess.run

```
import subprocess

command = "find {} -type d -empty -delete".format(folder_path)  
subprocess.run(command, shell=True)
```

It is just 3 lines code.

Following @tripleee's advice, the code can be written like this :

```
import subprocess
path = "your path here"
command = ["find", path, "-type", "d", "-empty", "-delete"]
subprocess.run(command)
```

Comment: That's rather silly. Probably see also [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess) (then refactor to take it out)

Comment: @tripleee Thank you for your comment. You are surely right. But if you don't add "shell=True" in the subprocess.run command, the script crashes and returns a "FileNotFoundError" error.

Comment: That's why I added the comment about refactoring. `subprocess.run("echo {} bar".format(foo), shell=True)` refactors to `subproces.run(["echo", foo, "bar"])`. This too is a common FAQ, and covered in the linked question.

Comment: @tripleee Understood. Thank you for your advice.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another version of the @rcgale answer. It replaces the any() loop with a set comparison to check for subdirs.

```py
def remove_empty_dirs(root_path):
    deleted_dirs = set()
    for current_dir, subdirs, files in os.walk(root_path, topdown=False):
        still_has_subdirs = set(subdirs).intersection(deleted_dirs) != set(subdirs)

        if not files and not still_has_subdirs:
            os.rmdir(current_dir)
            deleted_dirs.add(current_dir)

    return deleted_dirs
```

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you call this function, It is designed with an optional argument.
If you set `in_place` to `False` it will not remove the folders it will just return them as a list. Meanwhile, if you set it to `True` the function will remove the empty folders regardless of the subdirectories tree depth.

**P.S.** In case you need a depth limitation you can analyze it by elements after root path.

```py
import os
import shutil

def purge_dir(dir, in_place=False):

    deleted = []
    dir_tree = list(os.walk(dir, topdown=False))

    for tree_element in dir_tree:
        sub_dir = tree_element[0]
        is_empty = not len(os.listdir(sub_dir))
        if is_empty:
            deleted.append(sub_dir)

    if in_place:
        list(map(os.rmdir, deleted))

    return deleted
```

*I suggest* that you keep `in_place` set to `False` return back the empty folders and use it as you like since it is safer especially for security critical applications.

Answer (score 0):

This one fixes the problem with all the other answers. It avoids giving you a `PermissionDenied` error which stops the program from deleting folders.

```py
import os
import shutil

def remove_empty_folders(path_abs):
    walk = list(os.walk(path_abs))
    for path, _, _ in walk[::-1]:
        if len(os.listdir(path)) == 0:
            shutil.rmtree(path)
```